# AmCharts - cannot read property of 'time' of undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am using AmCharts. Everything is working fine except that when I try to put my own date objects in data, it won't work. But their example is working, still I did exactly what they did.

This is how I return my data (not working)

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 2);

var d2 = new Date();
d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 6);

chartData = 
[ 
    {"date":d1, "visits":150},
    {"date":d2, "visits":155}
];
return chartData;
```

This is how they return data in example (working)

```
var chartData = [];
var firstDate = new Date();
firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 150);

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {

    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var visits = Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 50);

    chartData.push({
        date: newDate,
        visits: visits
    });
}
return chartData;
```

I can't understand why am I getting an error in my console (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined)

Comment: Please post your full chart code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have an answer, if the zoomToIndexes is being used, it should have bounds set within the length of the chartData

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by setting the `dataDateFormat` property of my basic graph object and ensuring it matched the date format in my data. This appears to occur for multiple reasons, so this may well not be the only cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set date format as per your requirement,
for Eg,

```
 "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
```